# Customizer: save setting/control content to post/page

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes, theme-customizer

Is it possible to have a custom Customizer control/setting that saves the content in a new post/page instead of a theme mod/option.

Each control would be assigned a post/page, and that control would display a text field for the title `post_title` and textarea for `post_content` (also let it save as `draft`, the default). Also, if partial refresh would work, that would be awesome.

I know about the Customize Post plugin, I just need something simpler.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: As you say, it is possible due to the fact that Customize Posts exists. Without the infrastructure in Customize Posts there would be limitations to how you would be able to preview the post changes on your site, especially in the context of queries. Extracting the relevant bits from Customize Posts should get you what you need, but again it would be limited to your use case.